# Unabled to get fully JSON data in AXIOS

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

I am using React and Net core.
When data is called from react to axios, net core returns data in json format normally.
Bun in React, only part of json data is received.
Can i know the cause?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check your request response body from your chrome devtools (network tab )I don't think this has something to do with React!